# Can't add a newline when repeatedly appending onto a string

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I am trying to write to a text document with a specific format. Here's what I have right now.

```
    String line = "";
    double totalCost = 0;

    Node curr = summary.head.next;
    while(curr!=summary.tail)
    {
        line += [an assortment of strings and variables] +"\r";
        totalCost += PRICELIST.get(curr.itemName)*curr.count;
        curr = curr.next;
    }

        write.printf("%s" + "%n", line);
```

This is what the part adding onto line actually looks like.

```
"Item's name: " + curr.itemName + ", Cost per item: " +  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(PRICELIST.get(curr.itemName)) +
                ", Quantity: " + curr.count + ", Cost: " +  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(PRICELIST.get(curr.itemName)*curr.count) + "\r";
```

I've tried that with a newline character too. Before I had it working when the print statement was inside the loop meaning it only wrote one line at a time. I want to do it this way because I will have multiple threads writing to this file and this way any thread will not hold the lock for as long.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` instead of `println`?

Comment: I looked at a tutorial for how to write to file and it said that I had to use printf. I assumed that printf was just the thing that was used. Can you use println with a filewriter/printwriter?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it without problems with PrintWriter (which can wrap FileWriter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Java 7 or later you can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot. Do you know why I can't use escape characters when using a filewriter/printwriter?

Answer (score 1):

Use System.getProperty("line.separator") instead of "\r"

Cache ir for efficiency though.

Comment: This didn't work. The final result ended up having "null" printed where there should have been "\n".

Comment: Maybe you have misstyped "line.separator"? System.lineSeparator() has worked for you and that returns the initial value of the system property line.separator; as per the documentation of System.lineSeparator().

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use

```
while(..){
    result += newString
    ..
}
```

inside loop. This is very inefficient especially for long texts because each time you call

```
result += newString
```

you are creating new String which needs to copy content of `result` and append to it `newStrint`. So the more text you processed so far, the more it has to copy so it becomes slower.

Instead use

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(..){
     sb.append(newString);
}
result = sb.toString.
```

which in your case should be something more like

```
sb.append("Item's name: ").append(curr.itemName)
  .append(", Cost per item: ").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(PRICELIST.get(curr.itemName)))
  .append(", Quantity: ").append(curr.count )
  .append(", Cost: ").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(PRICELIST.get(curr.itemName) * curr.count))
  .append(System.lineSeparator());
```

Also instead of

```
write.printf("%s" + "%n", line);
```

you should use simpler version, which is

```
write.println(line);
```

which automatically add line separator based on OS.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get this in once I have my other stuff working.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to use `\n\r` in combination. This helped in one of my projects.